# Regex: Match until next match with Workflow app

Tags: ios, regex, workflow

I am trying to use the Workflow iOS app to separate and process text like the following:

```
Page 1, Highlight (Yellow):
  Content: "blah blah blah"

  "blah blah blah"

Page 111, Highlight (Yellow):
  Content: "more blah"

Page 524, Note (Yellow):
  Blah blah

  Blah blah Blah

Page 6, Highlight (Yellow):
  Content: "blah"
```

I would like to separate each chunk of text by page number, so that the above would result in 4 chunks of text. I can't figure a way to "split text" because I can't use new lines or a specific character.

Workflow on iOS has a function where you can group via a regex expression. This seems like it would work. I can write a regex that grabs "Page 1", but I can't figure out how to extend the match until the next instance of "Page XXX". I thought maybe something like this, but it's not working:

```
(Page)+ \w*[\s\S]*(?=\n.*?Page)
```

Would love any tips or guidance.

---

Edit: according to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/workflow/comments/76jfct/regex_possible_to_match_beginning_of_any_line/), Workflow requires ICU regex syntax. This should be of help to others.

This turned out to be the answer:

`(?sm)^Page.*?(?=^Page|\Z)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This should do the trick](https://regex101.com/r/Ag4bvl/2)

`(?s)^Page.*?(?=^Page|\Z)`

`(?s)` makes it so `.` will match new line characters

Then it looks for strings starting with "Page" and captures everything up until either the next line starting with "Page" or the last record.

Comment: thanks for helping! Unfortunately, that's not leading to a match. Maybe workflow doesn't accept the `(?s)`? (Regexr.com wasn't either).

Comment: It seems like that isn't supported for swift or objective C (which is what I assume you're using). Try this instead. [`^Page[\s\S]*?(?=^Page|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/Ag4bvl/3)

Comment: Ok, it looks like Workflow uses [ICU regex](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), so the first expression mostly works. For some reason, it only works if I take both carets out. With the carets, nothing. But without them, works great. If you know why that is, I'd love further help. But if not, this works pretty well. Thanks @emsimpson92 .

Comment: whoops, looks like this works, carets and all:

`(?sm)^Page.*?(?=^Page|\Z)`